# ValidationExpression for validator control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am using RegularExpressionValidator, for which i need the expression for the input having
6 characters. In which first letter should should be "M" and the rest 5 characters should be numbers.

how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Regex

```
^[Mm]\d{1,5}$
```

I have tested it and it's working, please check for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
^[M][0-9]{1,5}$
```

Comment: For a Regex Validator, you don't need the ^ and $ as the match must equal the whole input string.